# GPU MD5/SHA1 Hasher

Tags: cuda, md5, sha1, gpu, cal

I would like to make md5/sha1 hasher tool to calculate hash for large number of big files like movies. Basically this should be part of bigger project that will use that data to organize files.

I can do than on CPU with no problem but i will like to make tool that can use GPU(CUDA/CAL) and if there is no GPU only then to use CPU.

I did my search, but only md5 cracker result on google. Is there some tool or library that i can use, or i must write whole thing by myself?

I run into this
http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm
and
http://boinc.berkeley.edu/

but i would like some kind of library.

Answer (score 3):

Try to see [here](https://github.com/VladX/md5-bruteforcer), this project uses CUDA and x86/x64 CPU instructions.

Comment: hm, I guess it could be interesting, it is c code. But I was hoping to find some kind of library that can be used straight forward, without editing code, compiling ...